# Connecting to LDAP in oracle using sAMAccountName

Tags: oracle, ldap

i was trying to use `DBMS_LDAP` to connect to a ldap server to do authentication.

My question is:

Is it possible to use `sAMAccountName` to connect to the LDAP server? I'm getting the connection with the full name but wanted to do with the `sAMAccountName` but don't know how, i think `DBMS_LDAP.bind_s` and `DBMS_LDAP.simple_bind_s` don't permit the use of `sAMAccountName`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to use `bind_s` and `simple_bind_s` directly with the `sAMAccountName` by prefixing it with the [domain name](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1211943):

```
l_res := DBMS_LDAP.simple_bind_s(ld => l_session,
                                 dn => l_domain || '\' || l_account_name,
                                 passwd => l_password)
```

I tried to find additional information or reference in the Oracle documentation but I couldn't find anything on how to build the `dn` parameter. This seems to dependent upon the configuration of the AD server. In some settings, such as described in [this OTN forum post](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=282098), it seems to be possible to authenticate with `%LDAP_USER%@ourdomain.com`.

Comment: Your `l_account_name` is the sAMAccountName?

Comment: Yes, the account name was sAMAccountName (unique per domain), the domain name was the domain at the bottom of the window connection login screen.

Comment: So is something like this `l_domain := 'CN='||p_username||',OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx';` and `l_account_name := 'l_sAMAccountName'` ?

Comment: `l_domain` is the login domain. It should be a simple identifier (it's the value in the select list at the bottom of the windows network login screen).