# Does Oracle JDBC driver work with Active Directory authentication?

Tags: linux, oracle, jdbc, active-directory, driver

We need an officially supported JDBC driver for Oracle for Red Hat Linux that supports Active Directory authentication.

The Oracle database cannot have local database logons for end users. Only Active Directory functional accounts can be used. We can only use JDBC drivers for our RHEL applications to connect to that Oracle instance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Maybe helpful... [Connecting to LDAP in oracle using sAMAccountName](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7766962/608639) and [Configuration of Integration with Microsoft Active Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/idmanage.1012/b14085/odip_actdir003.htm).

Comment: Hi @jww : the developers in my scrum team will use JDBC driver to connect to the Oracle instance which authenticates via Active Directory. The issue is related to development. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.